# Missing keyword in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

What's wrong with this query?

I am getting following error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

My SQL:

```
CREATE Table ORDERDET
(
    ORDERID NUMBER,
    CUSTID NUMBER,
    PRODID NUMBER,
    ORDPRIORITY VARCHAR2(15),
    ORDDISCOUNT NUMBER(3,2),
    ORDSHIPMODE VARCHAR2(15),
    ORDDATE DATE,
    ORDSHIPDATE DATE,
    ORDSHIPCOST NUMBER(5,2),
    ORDQTY NUMBER,
    ORDSALES NUMBER(7,2),

    CONSTRAINT ch_ORDPRIORITY 
         CHECK (ORDPRIORITY IN ('Low', 'Medium', 'High',    'Critical', 'Not Specified')),
    CONSTRAINT ch_ORDSHIPMODE 
        CHECK (ORDSHIPMODE IN ('Regular Air','Delivery Truck','Express Air')),
    CONSTRAINT pk_ORDERDET 
        PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID, CUSTID, PRODID),

    CONSTRAINT fk_ORDERD 
        FOREIGN KEY (ORDERID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDERID) on DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_CUSTOMERORDER 
        FOREIGN KEY (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (CUSTID) on DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_PRODUCTORDER 
        FOREIGN KEY (PRODID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (PRODID) on DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Is `ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"` the entire message?  Isn't there a line number as well?

Comment: comment out all your constraints.  try to create the table.  Drop the table and try again adding one constraint at a time.  Watch your commas and closing bracket.

Comment: There is just a "Error starting at line : 641 in command -" from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC)

there is no `on DELETE RESTRICT` option, only `CASCADE` or `SET NULL` are allowed,
 please see attached syntax diagram below: 
[image]

---

I guess you want to prevent from deletion of a row in the parent table in a case when there are rows in the child table that references this parent row - if yes, then skip `ON DELETE` clause completely, because this is default behaviour of the foreign key constraint.

**----------
EDIT
----------**

> Error report - ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
>   02264. 00000 - "name already used by an existing constraint" *Cause: The specified constraint name has to be unique. *Action: Specify a
>   unique constraint name for the constraint.

The error message says, that one of a constraint name you have used in the create table has already been creaded (used) and you cannot use it again.
I think you haven't showed us the whole error message, because Oracle should print this duplicate name. 
Anyway, you can find which name is duplicate using this query:

```
select *
from user_objects
where object_name in (
'CH_ORDPRIORITY' ,
'CH_ORDSHIPMODE' ,
 'PK_ORDERDET' ,
'FK_ORDERD' ,
'FK_CUSTOMERORDER' ,
'FK_PRODUCTORDER'
)
```

If one (or a few) of these names are already used, then use a different name, say `FK_PRODUCTORDER_11` instead of `FK_PRODUCTORDER`

Comment: I run the code without ON DELETE, but still, it gives me an error message.

Comment: Did you get the same error message ? I run your statement without `ON DELETE` and get another error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` because referenced tables don't exists in my database - that's mean the syntax is now correct.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

Comment: I've edited my question, appended an explanation of a reason of  new error, and how to manage it.

Comment: Thank you! The table has finally been created. But still, I am not sure about one thing: why it is the case that adding ON DELETE RESTRICT would appear as an error type of "missing key word"

Comment: If you like my answer, then please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thank you. Regarding the error message - I really don't know why Oracle displays "missing keyword" in a case of wrong syntax. I don't like their error messages too, in many cases they are hard to understand and not user friendly.

Comment: ok,,,I see. This is the first time that I officially ask a question on stack overflow. :) I click on it now.

Comment: @ANDIII324 - it's well known that Oracle's error messages are terrible. You just have to get used to them. In this case "missing keyword" means that after `ON DELETE` Oracle expects a valid keyword, but it didn't find what it expected - therefore, the parse fails due to a "missing keyword".